# Sequential draw commands with glVertexAttribBinding not working as expected

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a struct Vertex{glm::vec4 t,n,v;}. I have written a obj loader that takes two parameters, obj file path as string and reference to a vector of 'Vertex'es. This function populates my vector and returns the number of indices(In my case indices are just sequential numbers, anyway).

As I have 6 objects to render, after using that function 6 times I have the following

```
vector<Vertex> objects[6];
GLint SIZES[6],OFFSETS[6],SIZES_I[6],OFFSETS_I[6];
```

filled. SIZES are number of 'Vertex'es(object[i].size()) and SIZES_I are number of indices. The offsets are calculated as below

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
  if(i==0)
  {
    OFFSETS[0]=0;OFFSETS_I[0]=0;
  }
  else
  {
    OFFSETS[i]=OFFSETS[i-1]+SIZES[i-1];
    OFFSETS_I[i]=OFFSETS_I[i-1]+SIZES_S[i-1];
  }
}
```

I transferred vectors of Vertex into a single VBO all back to back. Similarly for indices, transferred into buffer bound to element array buffer. That part is shown below.

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,(OFFSETS[5]+SIZES[5])*sizeof(Vertex),data,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
  glBindVertexBuffer(i,buffer[0],OFFSETS[i]*sizeof(Vertex),sizeof(Vertex));
}

glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,(OFFSETS_I[5]+SIZES_I[5])*sizeof(GLuint),indices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribFormat(0,4,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,offsetof(Vertex,v));
```

Now comes my problem. Of the two rendering codes shown below the first one doesn't work but the second works perfectly.

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
  glVertexAttribBinding(0,i);
  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,SIZES_I[i],GL_UNSIGNED_INT,reinterpret_cast<void*>(OFFSETS_I[i]*sizeof(GLuint));
}

//second

glVertexAttribBinding(0,0);
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
  glDrawElementsBaseVertex(GL_TRIANGLES,SIZES_I[i],GL_UNSIGNED_INT,reinterpret_cast<void*>(OFFSETS_I[i]*sizeof(GLuint)),OFFSETS[i]);
```

To summarily say what I have done so u guys can understand whats going on here, in the first case i created 6 buffer bindings on the same buffer with 6 offsets. In the second case there is only one binding, but I used base vertex to offset 6 times. Btw both are compiling, so ignore any typos as I typed all this in my tab.

**My first attempt at debugging:** Since base vertex approach is working, obj loader is fine. Anyway to make sure of it, I just loaded a single model. Its working fine.

**My second attempt at debugging:** My suspicion naturally fell on binding calls and offsets. To resolve this, I removed the for loop in the first method and initialized i with 0(Since second method i.e. base vertex method works, we dont bother with it). My first model appeared on screen. Next I initialized 'i' variable with 1. My second model was displayed on screen. This I repeated till i=5. Each of my 6 models were displayed correctly. So my models were displayed individually. But when I combine my calls sequentially, I get some full models, some partial models and some not at all.

**My third attempt at debugging:** It seems that only last 2 models and so are displayed. Remaining are not drawn or partially drawn. So I reversed my for loop starting with i=5 and decrementing. Now first 2 models and so are displayed(Here 'first two' and 'last two' refers to the order in which models are loaded in obj reader. I did not change that). It is as if the subsequent drawing commands are somehow making the work of earlier drawing commands vanish. Sort of.

Thats it. Here I hit a dead end. Any ideas what might be wrong or how I might proceed with further debugging?

Comment: Hey, I don't do a whole lot of c++ but this looks wrong: 
if(i==0)
OFFSETS[0]=0;OFFSETS_I[0]=0;. Because your if statement has no { }, the second line gets executed regardless of whether i equals 0. I consider it good practice to refrain from using these kind of if statements in general, though many people disagree.

Comment: Classic example of what happens when you type from the tablet... Copy pasted the code from my laptop. Thanks for pointing because other users may think thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that it is due to a bug in my driver. The same code worked in my colleague's computer.